# Universal Docking Station (USB-A) for 2019 Windows Laptop & 2015 Macbook Pro?

Tags: usb, dock

I'm interested in getting a docking station that works for both of these computers mainly to have multiple displays to work on:

- ASUS ZenBook UX433
- 2015 MacBook Pro A1502

I bought a [Targus universal docking station](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JBPNCQK) on eBay that connected via USB-A 3.0 but found that it was only working for the Zenbook.

I was hoping for a single connector/hub/docking station VS having individual cables setup for each computer (i.e. HDMI & USB-C for the Zenbook and HDMI & Thunderbolt for the Macbook). Based on the ports available on both computers I thought a USB-A 3.0 docking station would be my best bet.

Is what I'm attempting possible? Do I just need an adapter or purchase a different docking station? Will the Mac only extend displays if it's connected via Thunderbolt?

**UPDATE**
I found that the docking station *does* work for the MAC, but I needed to download the DisplayLink program/drivers. After doing that the additional monitors instantly started working!

Comment: Can you be more specific on the functionality you are looking for (apparently it is about video output, not general use), and the research you did so far?

Comment: Sorry I missed that in the original post. I want 2 additional monitors to look at regardless of which laptop is being used.

Comment: [Adding on] I was hoping for a single connector/hub/docking station VS having individual cables setup for each computer (i.e. HDMI & USB-C for the Zenbook and HDMI & Thunderbolt for the Macbook). Based on the ports available on both computers I thought a USB-A 3.0 docking station would be my best bet.

Comment: Please edit your question then, there is an edit link for it.